# Why would my ViewPager go out of bound inside a CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

For some reasons I can't grasp, the Viewpager in the image below overflows by the size of the menu. I'm probably not picturing something but I can't see what.

[image: As you can see the ViewPager which is selected goes out of bounds]

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        >
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ViewPager` goes out of bound because of the flag

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

that you've set in its **XML layout**. This us mainly used when you want to be able to use Google's Material Design scroll effects. If you're not interested in handling scrolls with the `CoordinatorLayout`, you can just delete that line.

Comment: Well, the ViewPager itself needs to be scrolled, but if I remove the app:layout_behaviour, I don't see the menu anymore;

Comment: You can keep the flag & use **NestedScrollView**s inside your `ViewPager` to work this out.

Comment: Plus, since you want the scroll effects then that means that you will display something **scrollable** inside your ViewPager, like a **RecyclerView**.

Comment: Check this amazing tutorial on the Google Material Design Library : https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout  It shall get you started.

Comment: Ok, will check since this totally puzzles me! I want a menu (the toolbar), a possibility to side scroll into different panels (the appbarlayout/view pager) and inside a panel I'd like to be able to have a list of images (inside the view pager here.)

Comment: Then that tutorial is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Wait, ok I just read the tutorial and I'm still quite puzzled. If I keep the flag in the ViewPager, then my viewpager will go over bounds, regardless of what I eventually inflate inside, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96428/discussion-between-jdev-and-gurg-hackpof).